# Copy the Value upto specific range using regular expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to capture the certain range of values using regular expression extractor in jmeter. Like "sessionid": "15F36C8A123D4483935062DDE73280CB\x2D0\x3A1",

In the above value I need to exclude the \x2D0\x3A1 and capture the value.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define two regular expression, assuming that x2 and x3 are good enough token to separate these two fields.

- 1st : x2([0-9A-Fa-f]+)
- 2nd : x3([0-9A-Fa-f]+)

Update: I misunderstood the original post and gave the solution to exclude the first part of the session id and extract the two values which seems like some range.

Comment: HI, I have just found the answer myself. It simple we need to just do the regular expression extractor as shown below: "sessionid": "(.+?)\\x2D0\\x3A1",             I hope it may be useful to some one.